# Camera feed gets lost when video is playing

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-camera

I am using Xamarin forms [mediaElement]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement view to play a video, but on top of the video should be a camera feed of the front camera, why does the camera feed gets lost when the video starts to play?

I am now using a grid to overlay the camera feed from the video player and here is what I have so far.

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                  RowSpacing="4">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <MediaElement  
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    Source="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
                    ShowsPlaybackControls="False"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <local:CameraPreview Camera="Front"
                                            Grid.Row="0"                         
                                            Grid.Column="1"/>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                                 Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And this is how it should be positioned.
[sample_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u4mW.png)
Any advice would be a great help ! Thanks.

Comment: You can use `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to achieve this simple layout like this screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf5pv.png, but the `MediaElement` always to be foreground when start to play the video.I tried the `CrossMediaManager` this plugin, I got the same result. I found a similar thread about it. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40580/play-video-in-background-like-spotify-using-xamarin-forms-and-android-renderer you can test it.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thanks for that. What I did is in the, Android camera CustomRenderer, I set the SetZOrderOnTop property of the camera surfaceView to true which forces the camera feed to be on top of the MediaElement player.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please post your solution to answer and mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.